# Rails routes concurrent permalinks fallback to another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I am trying to make nice urls on my site.
I have two resources: Pages and Blogs.

For both of them I defined permalinks:

```
def to_param
  permalink
end
```

I created custom routes in `routes.rb`:

```
get ':id', to: 'pages#show', as: :page
get ':id', to: 'blogs#show', as: :blog
```

Separately it works ok.

But turned on together I get this behavior:

If I enter `mysite.com/blog_link` (the permalink defined for Blog record) I get this error
`ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PagesController#show`

How can I define pages to fallback to next resource in `routes.rb` if record not found?

Answer (score -1):

You have two identical routes pointing to different resources. This is an error because the second resource will never be called.

You should prefix them

```
get 'pages/:id', to: 'pages#show', as: :page
get 'blogs/:id', to: 'blogs#show', as: :blog
```

Otherwise, the first route must have the logic to handle both the type of requests, including a fallback. In theory, you can route the `:id` path to an intermediate controller that first attempts to fetch a page and if it fails it will fetch the id.

But it's definitely not recommended, because ids may overlap.

Also please note that you are encouraged to use resources in your Rails routing. They will create the most common routes for you and handle path generations.

Comment: I want urls not to have prefixes, that is why I am asking. But the idea with intermediate controller is good for me. Can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: Also I have `resources :pages` and `resources :blogs`. My 'get's are written above to override default paths to use permalinks.